# VS2010 WPF project generated with wizard not compiled

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

With my VS2010/VS2012 is something happened and the WPF project does no longer compile. I have one big project which is possible to compile at another computers but no more at my laptop. I tried to create a new WPF project and this project does not compile either :(

I get an error:

> WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml.cs(25,7,25,26): error CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

I have looked for solution in google and I tried to reinstall VS2010 too.

Code generated by wizard:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

sreen shot from VS: http://msdojc.sk/error_CS0103/error_CS0103.JPG

zipped project: http://msdojc.sk/error_CS0103/WpfApplication2.7z

Sorry for my English.

Thank you for every idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find exactly what was a problem, but reinstall of framework solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The Build Action for the .xaml file must also be set to "Page", when moving a xaml file between projects this setting gets lost (in VS 2010 at least).

when you right click on the xaml file you'll find it in the properties window.

Comment: The build Action is set to "Page". I didn't touch the source code or settings of the project. I tried to compile generated WPF project from the wizard. I have copied the project on other coputers and there compiled without any problems. I suposed that it has to be something wrong with general settings of Visual Studio, but I can not find it :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of reinstalling again and again your VS any version. this is because you have changed the name of project or file somewhere in your WPF project, otherwise this error is not seen. this happens with us also if we try to change the name or folder for our file. Let say your file earlier was in a some Views folder and by chance or due to certain situation you moved it out of that folder but in the code to reach that xaml and xaml.cs file path remains same. so in order to make it work check everything is exactly what it should be. or if you need more help please provide more code or a screen shot of your solution also.

Comment: I compiled untouched source code which was generated with wizard. If I copy this project on other computer, there is the project possible to compile without any problems. I will attach a screen shot and whole project later (I need find a place where I can upload files)